# Application like the one in description

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have been developing Android apps, but never did a live wallpaper. I have seen one in the market, and just confused how to do a live wallpaper like the

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.anifree.anipet.aquarium

How do i do? Is it that i need to learn Animations in Android? Or is there anything else. Would love if you can give me a brief overview of how to develop things as in the app i gave!

Thanks
Nithin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140223/Create-a-live-aquarium-wallpaper-in-Android.aspx
cross-posted here: http://www.rajeeshcv.com/2010/12/create-a-live-aquarium-wallpaper-in-android/

Comment: It says "Service Unavailable"

Comment: Runs good for me, but just in case, I edited my answer to provide an alternate link.

Comment: Thanks, i found that few hours before, but it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [tutorial on how to make live wallpapers](http://blog.androgames.net/58/android-live-wallpaper-tutorial/). Its not too difficult, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! Looking for a better animation tutorial!